# focus() not working within setTimeout on iOS

Tags: jquery, css, focus

jQuery's focus() method is does not appear to work when used from within a setTimeout in iOS.

So,

```
setTimeout( function () {
    // Appears to have no effect in iOS, fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE
    $('.search').focus();    

}, 500);
```

But on it's own,

```
// works fine.
$('.search').focus();
```

See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwe44/ypjkH/1/

If the focus() call is made outside the setTimeout it works, inside it doesn't. This is doubly curious as other methods do work. For example, in my jsFiddle I'm able to change the border color, just not focus it. Any ideas?

Comment: I supposed it's remotely possible that focus via timer was being abused by some web pages and combined with the way the keyboard works on iOS, it created a bad user experience so Apple decided to block it.  I looked, but couldn't find any discussion of it on the web (though it's not obvious exactly what you would search for).

Comment: Hmmm, someone else has come to the same conclusion as you, http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134756-Buttons-click-handlers-and-the-iOS-keyboard this may be a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

Check fiddle i have updated  at http://jsfiddle.net/ypjkH/7/

```
    $('#selector').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout( doFocus  
    , 3000);

    });

  function doFocus() {
      $('.search').focus().css('border', '1px solid red');
  }
```

Comment: That's even more interesting. You've managed to trigger the focus css classes, but not invoke the keyboard, which is part of the point of focusing. I've no idea why your solution works better than mine, but it's certainly closer.

Comment: it focuses definitely wait for 3 seconds.

Comment: yup, it focuses, but the keyboard is not invoked, so you can't type anything. If you call `$('.search').focus()` from outside a `setTimeout` the keyboard is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Safari's approach to `focus` is that it will only work within the same event loop. Therefore, if it's inside a `Promise` or a timeout, it will not open the keyboard.

By today, it's impossible to open the keyboard **after** the timeout.

The only workaround you have is to use this hack:

```js
/**
 * iOS keyboard can only be opened by user interaction + focus event.
 * There are situations in which we need to open keyboard programmatically
 * before other elements are rendered, like when opening an overlay. this function can be used
 * to open the keyboard before the overlay is rendered, and once the overlay is
 * rendered, it's needed to focus to the desired input element, and the keyboard
 * will stay open.
 *
 * This function needs to be called from native events attached to HTML elements. It will
 * not work if called from a "passive" event, or after any event not coming from
 * user interaction (onLoad, onFocus, etc).
 *
 * It's recommended to use it on MouseEvents or TouchEvents.
 */
export function openIosKeyboard() {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: -100px; left: -100px;");
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.focus();
        // it's safe to remove the fake input after a 30s timeout
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(input);
        }, 30 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that autocompletion will not pop up. Autocompletion will be the worst nightmare if one needs it. One would need to add id attribute, and it still won't work well. It's a hack. The best one can do is to use a dedicated page with a form

Answer (score 0):

For my app it works, if you just put the x.focus() into a(nother) separate function and call it from within the setTimeout

Comment: I don't know how wrapping functions into other functions would ever work. Can you provide a working example?